# Block certain requests starting with specific string using .htaccess in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

```
54.215.234.39 - - [02/Apr/2014:10:51:35 -0400] "GET /ProductSearch.aspx?qs=94307 HTTP/1.1" 404 11414 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
```

I am getting a lot of these requests sent to my apache server from various ip addresses. We used to use a aspx based site. Now it's php. These requests are flooding the server. How can I block all requests that have the string "ProductSearch.aspx" in them?

Comment: Why are you not redirecting them to the new URLs?

Comment: We're seeing a sudden influx of these URLs. We moved over to php 2 years ago, and suddenly such type of request coming in look/sound fishy. Although we could, but I suspect these requests may perhaps be by some crawler, so we just want to block them.

Answer (score 3):

You could send a `403 Forbidden` (access denied) in case `/ProductSearch.aspx` is requested :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ProductSearch.aspx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

However, note that these requests will still reach your server and will appears in your `access.log` (but with a `403` instead of a `404`).

To avoid this you will have to filter before your web server. This could be done with a Reverse Proxy but this is a full other point.

---

Also, as mentionned by @Michael Hampton in comments, you could redirect all requests that ask for an `*.aspx` file to an `*.php` page.

(assuming, e.g, that `yourpage.aspx` has been replaced by `yourpage.php`) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(.*).aspx$ $1.php [R=301]
```

This will redirect

- `http://mydomain.com/ProductSearch.aspx?qs=94307`

to

- `http://mydomain.com/ProductSearch.php?qs=94307`